# how to rename an extracted file

Tags: java

I'm writing a java program that will extract zip file and rename the file inside it to the zip file name. For example: the zip file name is `zip.zip` and the file inside it is `content.txt`. Here i want to extract the zip file and the `content.txt` has to be renamed to `zip.txt`. I'm trying the below program.

And here there would be only one file in the zip file

**Zip.Java**

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipInputStream;

public class zip {
    private static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 4096;

    public void unzip(String zipFilePath, String destDirectory) throws IOException {
        File destDir = new File(destDirectory);
        if (!destDir.exists()) {
            destDir.mkdir();
        }
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(new FileInputStream(zipFilePath));
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        while (entry != null) {
            String filePath = destDirectory + File.separator + entry.getName();
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                extractFile(zipIn, filePath, zipFilePath);
            } else {
                // if the entry is a directory, make the directory
                File dir = new File(filePath);
                dir.mkdir();
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();
        }
        zipIn.close();
    }

    private void extractFile(ZipInputStream zipIn, String filePath, String zipFilePath) throws IOException {
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(filePath));

        byte[] bytesIn = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        int read = 0;
        while ((read = zipIn.read(bytesIn)) != -1) {
            bos.write(bytesIn, 0, read);
        }
        File oldName = new File(filePath);
        System.out.println(oldName);
        String str = zipFilePath.substring(zipFilePath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1, zipFilePath.lastIndexOf("."));
        System.out.println(str);
        File zipPath = new File(zipFilePath);
        System.out.println(zipPath.getParent());
        File newName = new File(zipPath.getParent() + "\\" + str);
        System.out.println(newName);
        if (oldName.renameTo(newName)) {
            System.out.println("Renamed");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Not Renamed");
        }

        bos.close();
    }

}
```

**UnZip.Java**

```
public class UnZip {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String zipFilePath = "C:\\Users\\u0138039\\Desktop\\Proview\\Zip\\New Companies Ordinance (Vol Two)_xml.zip";
        String destDirectory = "C:\\Users\\u0138039\\Desktop\\Proview\\Zip";
        zip unzipper = new zip();
        try {
            unzipper.unzip(zipFilePath, destDirectory);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here i was able to extract the file but unable to rename it. please let me knw where am i going wrong and how to fix it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close your BufferedOutputStream directly after the last write instruction (after the while loop). Only then will it release its lock on the file and will you be able to rename the file.

See: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#close()